# Does anyone know why <script src="scriptsource.js" /> doesn't work

Tags: javascript, xml, html, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

I've noticed that you can't slash-terminate a script tag when you specify a "src" and therefore don't require anything between the `<script>` and the `</script>`.  This is the only tag I know of where you can't do that.

For example, this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptsource.js"></script>
```

and this doesn't

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptsource.js" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `script` requires an end tag:

> Start tag: **required**, End tag:
>   **required**

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html

Comment: ahh, does the html4 specification supersede the xhtml spec?

Comment: @Tom the `script` end tag is required in all specs. Why has every single answer been down voted by someone?

Comment: cheers for the clarification, and I dunno, people too nice I guess? :P

Answer (score 3):

Here's your answer: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you have to have a closing tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptsource.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ahhh whoops. I reread the question. Disregard.

Comment: it does seem that you need a closing tag, however I'm more wondering WHY this is that case, rather than IF it is, thanks for your answer though

Comment: No problem - it seems to have been answered in the question linked by Scobal.